# Ubuntu VM 14.04 GUI

Tags: 14.04, gui

I have installed ubuntu VM image 14.04 and i used startx command to display the GUI ,it worked fine. 
After restarting the VM , I am not able to see the left side menu bar. However the menu bar is active but it is not visible at all . 
How to fix this?
Please guide.

Comment: if you are using virtualbox, install the virtualbox guest addons, it may be hidden becuase by default, ubuntu 14.04 starts into 800x600 screen resolution

Comment: Btw, AFAIK, in Ubuntu, it will showup  GUI login screen by default, unless you have manually booted to text mode. You will not need to run startx every time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your unity bar isn't automatically hidden?
The trick to show it is to move your mouse to the left side of the screen, and when it stops, move it left again (or press the super key).

This can be a tricky thing to do in a VM, so I suggest you go in fullscreen mode (right-CTRL + F).

If it is hidden automatically, go to settings -> appearance -> behaviour and turn off auto-hide the Launcher.